# Android: using 9-patch and text for ItemizedOverlay on MapView

Tags: android, google-maps, overlay, android-mapview

In my application I would like to mark different spots on a map. What I'm now wondering is if there's a way to use a simple 9-patch image and add the spot's name as text to it or would I need to draw everything myself (including the text) in the `draw()` method of `ItemizedOverlay`?

Answer (score 3):

As per this Q&A:

> [Drawing Nine Patch onto Canvas (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127438/drawing-nine-patch-onto-canvas-android)

you should be able to load the 9-patch using [Resources.getDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getDrawable(int)), set the drawing bounds using [Drawable.setBounds](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#setBounds(android.graphics.Rect)), and finally draw to the canvas provided in `onDraw` using [Drawable.draw](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#draw(android.graphics.Canvas)).

If you plan on reusing the drawable, you should keep an eye out for memory leaks, per [this article](http://www.curious-creature.org/2008/12/18/avoid-memory-leaks-on-android/).

Comment: Stefan-- did my response work out for you? If not, feel free to follow up.