# CCScale9Sprite vs NinePatchDrawable?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, nine-patch

I'm interested in experimenting with 9Patch bitmaps.  There's a ton of guides on how to make the PNGs (which is very easy) but not much on how to actually code the 9.PNGs into your code ([other than the occasional forum post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079868/create-a-ninepatch-ninepatchdrawable-in-runtime)).

Is there any advantage to using NinePatchDrawable over Cocos2D's CCScale9Sprite?  NinePatchDrawable's look quite complicated!

Comment: Have you noticed that NinePatchDrawable is for Android? So this isn't really an either/or choice if you're using cocos2d-iphone. PS: stackoverflow is not a forum (discussions), it's a Q&A site (ask questions, get answers).

Comment: Yes, sorry I should have said I'm looking at Android apps not iPhone.  And I meant forms across the internet, not just posts on stackoverflow.  Just seen this post which makes NinePatch look quite easy to implement:  [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127438/drawing-nine-patch-onto-canvas-android[link]